# Access loopback context/request from the model overridables

Tags: loopbackjs

How is it possible to access the loopback context (or simple Express req object) from within the model's logic?

It is critical to be able to know more about the request itself (current user identity more than anything else) inside the model's logic. When I override a built-in method (via custom script or from the model.js file) or develop a custom remote method, I would like to access the Express req object.

As loopback.getCurrentContext() is declared to be buggy, I cannot use it.

Ideas?

PS:
I find this page confusing: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-current-context.html

First it's said (and marked in red as important!) it is not recommended to use LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext() and then it's used it in each example!?

What's the point to give examples that do not work? Should we simply ignore the complete page? If so, what about the context? :)

Any clarification on this topic is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to express req object by using remote hooks

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
module.exports = function (MyModel) {

 MyModel.beforeRemote('findOne', function (ctx, model, next) {
   //access to ctx.req
   console.log(ctx.req.headers) 
   next()         
 })

 MyModel.beforeRemote('my-custom-remote-method', function (ctx, model, next) {
   console.log(ctx.req.headers)
   next()
 }) 

}
```

Comment: I know that, but, as I stated, I want to access it from the model's built-in CRUD methods (precisely their overrided version). I don't have problem accessing the context from remote hooks, even remote methods themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a `beforeRemote` hook to modify the `ctx.args` property. This property is the input of the remote method (that is, custom or built-in). This way, you can copy a part of the request inside this property, and it will be passed to the build-in method

**Example 1** with the built-in method `findOne`.

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('findOne', function (ctx, model, next) {
   ctx.args.filter.extrafield = ctx.req.headers['some-header'];
   next();         
 });
```

Then [override](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models#Customizingmodels-Viayourmodel'sscript) the findOne method since it's what you want to do

```
MyModel.on('dataSourceAttached', function(obj){
    var findOne = MyModel.findOne;
    MyModel.findOne = function(filter, cb) {
      console.log(filter.extrafield); // Print what was in the header
      return findOne.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
```

And finally call the method with curl

```
curl -H "some-header: 'hello, world!'" localhost:3000/api/MyModel/findOne
```

**Example 2** with a custom remote `printToken`, to help you understand further

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('printToken', function (ctx, model, next) {
  ctx.args.token = ctx.req.headers['some-header'];
  next();         
});

MyModel.printToken = function(token, cb) {
  console.log(token);
  cb();
}

MyModel.remoteMethod(
  'printToken', 
  {
    accepts: {arg: 'token', type: 'string', optional: true}
  }
);
```

Then call the remote with curl, and pass the expected header

```
 curl -H "some-header: 'hello, world!'" localhost:3000/api/MyModel/printToken
```

**EDIT:** There is a simpler solution that **only works for custom remote**

When defining your remote method, it is possible to tell loopback to pass elements of the http request to your remote directly as an input argument

```
MyModel.remoteMethod(
  'printToken', 
  {
    accepts: [
     {arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
     {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}}
    ]
  }
);
```

This way, your remote can access the req and res objects. This is documented [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-HTTPmappingofinputarguments)

Comment: I don't think ctx is passed to the built-in CRUD methods, that's the whole problem. Can you show an example of that?

Comment: `ctx` itself is not passed, but `ctx.args` is passed. `ctx.args` is precisely the data passed to your CRUD method.

Comment: Say your remote accepts a parameter `filter` of type `object`, then `ctx.args` will contain a property `filter`

Comment: Cak you give an example?

Comment: I have provided full examples with built-in and remote.